# How to map Null Pointer Exception in Jersey server

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jersey-client

I have jersey client and jersey server.
For customized exception, I have created a provider class which implements
avax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper and I am returning like

```
ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse();
return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(errorResponse).type(
            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).build();
```

Now in client i am doing like below

```
if (response.getStatus() == Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {

    CustomeResponse cresponse = response
                    .getEntity(CustomeResponse.class);
}else{
ErrorResponse errorResponse = response
                    .getEntity(ErrorResponse.class);
throw new CustomException(errorResponse.getErrorMessage(),
                    errorResponse.getErrorCode());

}
```

But whenever my server has null pointer exception I am getting the below exception in the client

```
Aug 19, 2014 12:03:37 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.custom.exception.ErrorResponse, and Java type class com.custom.exception.ErrorResponse, and MIME media type text/html; charset=utf-8 was not found
Aug 19, 2014 12:03:37 PM com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse getEntity
SEVERE: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider

Aug 19, 2014 12:03:37 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can I map null pointer and other runtime exception to throw useful error code at client.
Please help and suggest.

Comment: What version of Jersey are you using and what serializer? There were bugs in Jersey prior to 2.6 using MOXy with the very scenario.

Comment: Hi I was able to overcome this issue by creating provider for runtime exception.I am using 1.1.17.